# Random non-related errors in Visual Studio 2015 when implementing an enum

Tags: c#, enums, visual-studio-2015

Like the title suggests, i get random errors which dissapear when i comment out the enum related stuff. Ive commented where the errors appear and what vs tells me.

```
namespace Overbox
{
    class UpdateHandler
    {
        public enum GameState { MainMenu, Options, Playing, GameOver, Exiting };

        public UpdateHandler()
        //Below bracket tells me "} expected" (ive counted and unless i cant do basic math there is a correct amount of brackets)
        {
            public GameState currentGameState = GameState.MainMenu;
        }
        //Update tells me "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods" even though it actually is (even if the formatting is messing up a bit)
        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The final bracket tells me "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to declare a field from within a constructor:

```
public UpdateHandler()
//Below bracket tells me "} expected" (ive counted and unless i cant do basic math there is a correct amount of brackets)
{
    public GameState currentGameState = GameState.MainMenu;
}
```

C# does not allow this, you'll have to take the declaration outside:

```
public GameState currentGameState;

public UpdateHandler()
{
    currentGameState = GameState.MainMenu;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set the value of your field outside of the constructor:

```
public GameState currentGameState = GameState.MainMenu;

public UpdateHandler()
{

}
```

It looks to me as if this is what you were trying to achieve, but got the positioning slightly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

your code should look like this.

```
namespace Overbox
{
    class UpdateHandler
    {
        public enum GameState 
        { 
            MainMenu, 
            Options, 
            Playing, 
            GameOver, 
            Exiting 
        };

        public GameState currentGameState;

        public UpdateHandler()
        {
            this.currentGameState = GameState.MainMenu;
        }
        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

        }
    }
}
```